# Word to describe someone briskly touching another

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to refer to the act of a person grabbing onto, and almost manhandling, another person in a non-sexual and non-confrontational manner? For example, how [Kirk is grabbing onto Spock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAvRBDQqSmY)? I was thinking of a word similar to grappling. I was also thinking of embrace, but I'm not thinking of so much contact that it would be considered a hug. I'm alright with a phrase if not a single word.

The two extremes would be a handshake and a hug. I am searching for an inbetweener.

Comment: I want to say this is just _a hold_.

Comment: Clasp? Clutch hold? Squeeze?

Comment: What's wrong with "grab"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [grasp](http://To%20take%20hold%20of%20or%20seize%20firmly%20with%20the%20hand,%20the%20foot,%20another%20body%20part,%20or%20an%20instrument:):

> - To take hold of or seize firmly with the hand, the foot, another body part, or an instrument:
> - To hold with the arms; embrace.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

To clap, as in strike or slap someone encouragingly on the back.

```
> slap (someone) encouragingly on the back or shoulder. "as they parted,
> he clapped Owen on the back" synonyms: slap, strike, hit, smack,
> thump; pat; informal whack, thwack "he clapped Owen on the back"
```

Comment: Clasp seems to be a very brief period of touch. I'm looking for something that lasts several seconds, such as how Kirk grabs onto Spock.

Comment: Does "latch onto" get at it?